# How to rename MS Access table with relationships using SQL?

Tags: sql, .net, ms-access

I'm connecting to an MS Access database from an external .Net application. I need to use SQL in order to upgrade the schema of the database. Part of the upgrade requires renaming a table that is part of a 1-to-many relationship.

I understand that it is not possible to actually rename a table in MS Access using SQL. My research has led me to the following solution.

```
SELECT * INTO OldTableName FROM NewTableName
DROP TABLE OldTableName
```

This appears to work correctly for tables that are not part of a relationship. However, if the table belongs to a relationship, then I receive the following exception when running the DROP TABLE SQL.

```
Cannot delete this index or table.  It is either the current index or is used in a relationship.
```

Is there a way via SQL that I can update the relationship in MS Access to point to the new table that has been created so the old table can be dropped?

Comment: You need to drop old foreign key constraint before table deleting and then create new one

Comment: OK, but could you elaborate on this? Perhaps with some SQL, which is what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably save yourself some grief by simply using Access DAO to rename the table:

```cs
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;

namespace AccessDaoConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbe = new DBEngine();
            Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb");
            TableDef tbd = db.TableDefs["OldTableName"];
            tbd.Name = "NewTableName";
            db.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The .NET project will require a COM reference for Access DAO. The one I used was

> Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library

Comment: This would require the end user's computer to have Office installed though right?

Comment: @user1227445 - No, Access DAO is part of the Access Database Engine. If they can do Access OLEDB/ODBC then they can do Access DAO too.

Comment: But where does that come from? The end user would have to have Access installed then right?

Comment: To clarify, the end user is not using Access. They are using my application, which just happens to use an Access format database under the hood, which is managed by a 3rd party library, so the user doesn't need to have Access installed for my application to work.

Comment: @user1227445 - Lots of applications use the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) without having the full version of Microsoft Access installed (by itself, or as part of Microsoft Office). Does this "3rd party library" use the Access Database Engine, or does it use some other approach like UCanAccess does (it uses Jackcess to modify the database file)?

Comment: OK. I actually have no idea what it uses. I assume it must use the Access Database Engine. I'd have to test the code on a machine that doesn't have Office or Access installed and see what happens. Would prefer to use SQL though, even if it is more of a hassle. I'm guessing I need to drop the old relationship first, then create a new relationship after the old table has been dropped.

Comment: Well, tried the code out, but as I suspected, it requires the Office API, which I'm not using. MSDN confirmed this too. Oh well, back to my original question. How do I do this with SQL only?

Answer (score 0):

You should drop foreign key constrain first. How to do this using SQL you can see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468774/how-do-i-drop-and-unamed-relationship-constraint-in-ms-access-with-sql). Then create new constraint:

```
alter table City
   add constraint FK_City_REF_States foreign key (ID_State)
      references States (ID_State);
```

Comment: I just recently found that same post and tried doing exactly as you said. The problem is that when I try to remove the constraint I get an error telling me that I don't have permission to read from Msysrelationships, so that basically killed that idea. Not sure why it was accepted as the answer to that question if you can't actually read from that table.

Comment: There are few ways to read this table from outside of Access, you can search for this. But actually you don't need to read this table from outside if the database is under your control and not changed dynamically. Just open accdb an Access, read constraint names once and use them in .net code