# Rename access table name using C# using oledb

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

Im currently working on a project and I need to rename Access Table names programaticaly in C#.

Unlike SQL, Access does not have a sp_rename stored procedure, so how would I go about this in code for an Access db using an oledb connection?

on click event I am trying this

```
 private void TSLmEng_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = 2;
            System.Globalization.FormLanguageSwitchSingleton.Instance.ChangeLanguage(this, CultureInfo);
            ini.IniWriteValue("CultureInfo", "LanguageIndex", comboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString());
            ini.IniWriteValue("CultureInfo", "Language", CultureInfo.ToString());
            this.Refresh();
        }

        private void tmgermany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
            System.Globalization.FormLanguageSwitchSingleton.Instance.ChangeLanguage(this, CultureInfo);
            ini.IniWriteValue("CultureInfo", "LanguageIndex", comboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString());
            ini.IniWriteValue("CultureInfo", "Language", CultureInfo.ToString()); 
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: above link it show me how to rename the column not table name

Comment: The marked duplicate is not a duplicate at all, hence voting to reopen.

Comment: Why do you have to do it using an oledb connection? It's certainly possible using DAO.

Comment: Can you help me out for DOA

Comment: Well, first of all, you're not sharing any sample code for me to work with. Secondly, the question is closed, so I can't answer it. Thirdly, try to do some research yourself, then ask for help. There are enough questions/answers pertaining to how to create a DAO connection, and how to rename tables using DAO.

Comment: if you have link please share with me I dnt know how to start

Comment: Nope. You've accepted the duplicate yourself, you're not sharing code, and you've reverted the edit I made actually picking the appropriate tag for your question. I don't have them lying around, I would have to search, and you might as well do that yourself. Put in at least some effort.

Comment: (a) Oops - sorry - I just corrected the tag from the inappropriate [access] to the appropriate [ms-access].  I didn't notice that you were explicitly reverting tag changes back to inappropriate ones.  Feel free to change it back again if you like so that the question can be downvoted for being an access control question which doesn't even mention what access control issues exist. (b) "I dnt know how to start" - try going to www.google.com and entering "how to rename tables using DAO" as a search phrase.

Comment: please see the updated question

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45350804/2144390) shows how to rename a table from C# using DAO.